# iOS: Launch app from facebook

Tags: html, ios, facebook

We currently have a custom url scheme that launches our app when the user browses to the page via mobile safari, however I have had zero success getting our app to launch when a link is clicked or view via Facebook's Messenger webview and I am not quite sure why.

I have tried setting the `target` attribute to `_blank` which seems to be the only suggestion I can find, however it does not work.

So to my question is, how can I get our ios app to launch from Facebook Messenger's Webview?

Comment: This is the thing you are looking for:- http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

The feature I was looking for was Universal Linking which was just appears to be added in iOS 9 and required some additional setup for it to work.

See link below: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html